# Help with SQL join

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables a) `BOOKS (id,name)` b) `RATINGS (book id,rating,ip address)` c) `comments (comment_id,book id,comments,date)`

I want to show BOOK NAME,RATING,Number of COMMENTS using left join.

The issue with my query is it shows different ratings if the number of comments changes.
For example if there is one comment for a book the data returned by sql is perfect but the moment more comments are added the rating appears incorrect.

```
SELECT
    book.id,
    book.name,SUM( rtng.rating ) As total_rating,
    COUNT(distinct cmt.comment_id ) AS comment_count
FROM books book
    LEFT JOIN ratings rtng ON rtng.book_id = book.id
    LEFT JOIN comments cmt ON cmt.book_id = book.id
```

Comment: you need some GROUP BY clause

Comment: You need to use a GROUP BY (maybe 'GROUP BY book.id'). The DISTINCT clause will not work for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way, you can get ALL books regardless of any missing a rating or comment...  The primary table is books then do left join to each comment and rating respectively.

```
select
      B.ID,
      B.Name,
      COALESCE( TR.Rating, 0 ) TotalRating,
      COALESCE( TR.AvgRating, 0 ) AvgRating,
      COALESCE( COM.CommentCnt, 0 ) TotalComents
   FROM
      Books B
         LEFT JOIN ( select R.Book_ID,
                            SUM( R.Rating ) Rating,
                            AVG( R.Rating ) AvgRating
                        FROM Ratings R
                        Group By R.Book_ID ) TR
            ON B.ID = TR.Book_ID

         LEFT JOIN ( select C.Book_ID, 
                            count(*) CommentCnt
                        FROM Comments C
                        Group by C.Book_ID ) COM
            ON B.ID = COM.Book_ID
```

Comment: subquery is one of the solution but i don't want to use subquery.Do you think you can help me?

Comment: @Gautam, I don't think you can without one... Whenever you have one table to multiple tables that can have multiple records per ID, you will always have the possibility of what you are encountering.  The way your query is currently, you are running into a Cartesian result which is throwing off your SUM() valuation.  At a minimum, you could do with your query summing and optionally averaging as long as you apply a SINGLE subquery of the comment counts per book and join to that.

Answer (score 0):

This likely has to do with the fact that the relationship between the `books` table and the `comments` (and `ratings`) tables is "one to many". You're going to have to do at least two queries:

(pseudocode follows)

```
all_book_ids = SELECT book_id FROM books

foreach a_single_book in all_book_ids
    SELECT * FROM comments WHERE book_id = a_single_book
    SELECT * FROM ratings  WHERE book_id = a_single_book
```

Answer (score 0):

How about grouping based in books ID and additionally computing the average rating?

```
SELECT book.id,
       book.name,
       SUM( rtng.rating )              AS total_rating
       AVG( rtng.rating )              AS averageRating,
       COUNT(distinct cmt.comment_id ) AS comment_count
  FROM books                           AS book
  LEFT JOIN ratings rtng 
         ON rtng.book_id = book.id
  LEFT JOIN comments cmt 
         ON cmt.book_id = book.id    
  GROUP BY book.id
```

Comment: Thanks for help but this query gives incorrect total rating. i have 4 rating for a particular book 5,5,5,5 so the total rating should be 20 but it shows 40. If there is 1 comment for this book then the total rating shows correct value but the moment there is more than 1 comment it gives incorrect total rating. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

one more

```
SELECT book.id,book.name,
rtng.total_rating,
cmt.comment_count
from books book 
LEFT JOIN 
(
select book.id,book.name, SUM( rtng.rating ) As total_rating
from books book
inner join ratings rtng 
ON rtng.book_id = book.id 
group by book.id,book.name
)rtng 
ON rtng.book_id = book.id 

LEFT JOIN 
(
select book.id,book.name, COUNT(*) AS comment_count 
from books book
    left join comments cmt 
    ON cmt.book_id = book.id
group by book.id,book.name
)cmt 
ON cmt.book_id = book.id
```

Comment: subquery is one of the solution but i don't want to use subquery.Do you think you can help me?